# What class is used in this iphone app

Tags: iphone, image, mkmapview

I've been long time searching for a way to achieve placing pins on an image just like the mapview, but have not been able to do this yet. I thought someone could give a clue as what kind of class is used in [this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNKlx.jpg)As you can see everything is like MKMapView with Annotation pins and callout except for that it's not a map but an ordinary image. How can I achive the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, basically a matter of creating the pin image, then placing image views of that image over your background image.  Create the image view, set it's position as needed, and call addSubview from the background image.

Comment: I do exactly as you said. So you think this is the only way? No way to subclass MKMapView and add a UIImage property?

Comment: Can't say -- I've never used MKMapView.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a simple way, first find out the position of the user tap on the image or screen. Then place that pin image on that tap position in such a manner the height of the pin image should point the y axis of the tap. If you want to store that data then store it in some array or file and you can also save that image (the map containing pins) as png.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried exactly what you said. But I can't anhow pop up callouts like the one in the picture.

Comment: Are you talking about animation?? or something else?

Comment: Not animation. You see the bubble box which writes Nasal Bone and has a disclosure button on it? I mean that.

Comment: Ok. For that you can create a UIView and trace the user tab position and then fill values(a label inside a view) in that view according to the screen area. I cann't give u the exact code for it. Juss trying to tell you the logic. It may help you.